# How to make awkward pivot of sql table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have to rotate a given table from an SQL Server but a normal pivot just doesn't work (as far as i tried). So has anybody an idea how to rotate the table into the desired format?

Just to make the problem more complicated, the list of given labels can vary and it is possible that a new label name can come into at any given time.

#### Given Data

```
ID |  Label          |  Numerator  |  Denominator  |  Ratio 
---+-----------------+-------------+---------------+--------
1  |  LabelNameOne   |  41         |  10           |  4,1   
1  |  LabelNameTwo   |  0          |  0            |  0     
1  |  LabelNameThree |  21         |  10           |  2,1   
1  |  LabelNameFour  |  15         |  10           |  1,5   
2  |  LabelNameOne   |  19         |  19           |  1     
2  |  LabelNameTwo   |  0          |  0            |  0     
2  |  LabelNameThree |  15         |  16           |  0,9375
2  |  LabelNameFive  |  19         |  19           |  1     
2  |  LabelNameSix   |  17         |  17           |  1     
3  |  LabelNameOne   |  12         |  12           |  1     
3  |  LabelNameTwo   |  0          |  0            |  0     
3  |  LabelNameThree |  11         |  12           |  0,9167
3  |  LabelNameFour  |  12         |  12           |  1     
3  |  LabelNameSix   |  0          |  1            |  0
```

#### Wanted result

```
ID | ValueType   | LabelNameOne | LabelNameTwo | LabelNameThree | LabelNameFour | LabelNameFive | LabelNameSix
---+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+--------------
1  | Numerator   | 41           | 0            | 21             | 15            |               |              
1  | Denominator | 10           | 0            | 10             | 10            |               |              
1  | Ratio       | 4,1          | 0            | 2,1            | 1,5           |               |              
2  | Numerator   | 19           | 0            | 15             |               | 19            | 17           
2  | Denominator | 19           | 0            | 16             |               | 19            | 17           
2  | Ratio       | 1            | 0            | 0,9375         |               | 1             | 1            
3  | Numerator   | 12           | 0            | 11             | 12            |               | 0            
3  | Denominator | 12           | 0            | 12             | 12            |               | 1            
3  | Ratio       | 1            | 0            | 0,9167         | 1             |               | 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should sort you out.  It's really an UNPIVOT and a PIVOT.  Note that you have to conform your data because the UNPIVOT puts all the data in the same column.

Note that I had to recreate/repopulate the table variable in the inner dynamic SQL - typically this is not necessary when dealing with a permanent table.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON ;

DECLARE @pivot_cols AS varchar(max) ;
DECLARE @src AS TABLE
    (
     ID int NOT NULL
    ,Label varchar(14) NOT NULL
    ,Numerator int NOT NULL
    ,Denominator int NOT NULL
    ,Ratio decimal(5, 4) NOT NULL
    ) ;

DECLARE @label_order AS TABLE
    (
     Label varchar(14) NOT NULL
    ,Sort int NOT NULL
    )

INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameOne', 41, 10, 4.1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameThree', 21, 10, 2.1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameFour', 15, 10, 1.5) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameOne', 19, 19, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameThree', 15, 16, 0.9375) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameFive', 19, 19, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameSix', 17, 17, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameOne', 12, 12, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameThree', 11, 12, 0.9167) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameFour', 12, 12, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameSix', 0, 1, 0) ;

INSERT  INTO @label_order
VALUES  ('LabelNameOne', 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @label_order
VALUES  ('LabelNameTwo', 2) ;
INSERT  INTO @label_order
VALUES  ('LabelNameThree', 3) ;
INSERT  INTO @label_order
VALUES  ('LabelNameFour', 4) ;
INSERT  INTO @label_order
VALUES  ('LabelNameFive', 5) ;
INSERT  INTO @label_order
VALUES  ('LabelNameSix', 6) ;

WITH    Labels
          AS (
              SELECT  DISTINCT
                        src.Label
                       ,ISNULL(label_order.Sort, 0) AS Sort
              FROM      @src AS src
              LEFT JOIN @label_order AS label_order
                        ON src.label = label_order.label
             )
    SELECT  @pivot_cols = COALESCE(@pivot_cols + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Label, '[')
    FROM    Labels
    ORDER BY Sort
           ,Label ;

DECLARE @template AS varchar(max) ;

SET @template = '
DECLARE @src AS TABLE
    (
     ID int NOT NULL
    ,Label varchar(14) NOT NULL
    ,Numerator int NOT NULL
    ,Denominator int NOT NULL
    ,Ratio decimal(5, 4) NOT NULL
    ) ;

INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameOne'', 41, 10, 4.1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameTwo'', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameThree'', 21, 10, 2.1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameFour'', 15, 10, 1.5) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameOne'', 19, 19, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameTwo'', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameThree'', 15, 16, 0.9375) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameFive'', 19, 19, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameSix'', 17, 17, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameOne'', 12, 12, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameTwo'', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameThree'', 11, 12, 0.9167) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameFour'', 12, 12, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameSix'', 0, 1, 0) ;

WITH    src_conformed
          AS (
              SELECT    ID
                       ,Label
                       ,CAST (Numerator AS decimal(10, 4)) AS Numerator
                       ,CAST (Denominator AS decimal(10, 4)) AS Denominator
                       ,CAST (Ratio AS decimal(10, 4)) AS Ratio
              FROM      @src
             ),
        UNPIVOTED
          AS (
              SELECT    *
              FROM      src_conformed UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN (Numerator, Denominator, Ratio) ) AS unpvt
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    UNPIVOTED PIVOT ( SUM(Val) FOR Label IN ({@pivot_cols}) ) AS pvt
    ORDER BY ID
           ,Col ;' ;

SET @template = REPLACE(@template, '{@pivot_cols}', @pivot_cols) ;

EXEC (@template) ;
```

Comment: This looks awesome. Even that you added my test data as temp table is absolutely great. If i could give you more rep than i already had (+1 and marked as correct) i would do so. Thousand thanks.

Comment: After successfully using your version i just have one minor issue i just can't solve. In the result the order of the three lines is alphabetical, but i'd like to get the order Num..., Den..., Ratio within one ID. Any ideas how to get that?

Comment: @Oliver Use the same technique I used to make the @label_order table.  I noticed that and figured you would see how I solved the column order and use the same technique.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've seen that, but cause i didn't need it in my concrete problem this was the first one i delete. And when i need it for the Col i just didn't remembered.

Comment: @Oliver No problem - this sample code was probably longer and more complicated than the code needed to be in your system since you will already have permanent tables for all these things.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
id,
'Numerator' as ValueType,
case when label = labelNameOne then Numerator else 0 end as LabelNameOne,
case when label = labelNameTwo then Numerator else 0 end as LabelNameTwo,
case when label = labelNameTree then Numerator else 0 end as LabelNameTree,
case when label = labelNameFour then Numerator else 0 end as LabelNameFour,
case when label = labelNameFive then Numerator else 0 end as LabelNameFive,
case when label = labelNameSix then Numerator else 0 end as LabelNameSix

union All
```

... similar query with Denominator ...

```
union all
```

... similar query with Ratio...

Comment: yes, this was one of my tries, but unfortunately the list of labels can vary, so i can't exactly name the labels in the case statements. Do you know of any way to create the cases from a given list like `select distinct Label from table`?

Answer (score 1):

What you seek is dynamic cross tab. The short answer is that it cannot be done in T-SQL without some fugly dynamic SQL. The Hoyle answer is that you should pivot the data in a reporting tool or in the middle tier.

Comment: Yes, that's the direction i'm currently running (doing it on myself in C++), but i thought, that maybe someone knows another way directly in SQL.