# How to make additional columns on pivot of sql table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

After getting such a great feedback from [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433533/how-to-make-awkward-pivot-of-sql-table-in-sql-server-2005). Maybe someone can help me with this problem also.

I have to rotate a given table from an SQL Server but a normal pivot just doesn't work (as far as i tried). So has anybody an idea how to rotate the table into the desired format?

Just to make the problem more complicated, the list of given labels can vary and it is possible that a new label name can come into at any given time.

#### Given Data

```
ID |  Label          |  Numerator  |  Denominator  |  Ratio 
---+-----------------+-------------+---------------+--------
1  |  LabelNameOne   |  41         |  10           |  4,1   
1  |  LabelNameTwo   |  0          |  0            |  0     
1  |  LabelNameThree |  21         |  10           |  2,1   
1  |  LabelNameFour  |  15         |  10           |  1,5   
2  |  LabelNameOne   |  19         |  19           |  1     
2  |  LabelNameTwo   |  0          |  0            |  0     
2  |  LabelNameThree |  15         |  16           |  0,9375
2  |  LabelNameFive  |  19         |  19           |  1     
2  |  LabelNameSix   |  17         |  17           |  1     
3  |  LabelNameOne   |  12         |  12           |  1     
3  |  LabelNameTwo   |  0          |  0            |  0     
3  |  LabelNameThree |  11         |  12           |  0,9167
3  |  LabelNameFour  |  12         |  12           |  1     
3  |  LabelNameSix   |  0          |  1            |  0
```

#### Wanted result

```
ID | LabelNameOneNumerator | LabelNameOneDenominator | LabelNameOneRatio | LabelNameTwoNumerator | LabelNameTwoDenominator | LabelNameTwoRatio | LabelNameThreeNumerator | LabelNameThreeDenominator | LabelNameThreeRatio | ...
---+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+-----
1  | 41                    | 10                      | 4,1               | 0                     | 0                       | 0                 | 21                      | 10                        | 2,1                 | ...
2  | 19                    | 19                      | 1                 | 0                     | 0                       | 0                 | 15                      | 16                        | 0,9375              | ...
3  | 12                    | 12                      | 1                 | 0                     | 0                       | 0                 | 11                      | 12                        | 0,9167              | ...
```

I know, after getting such a good answer for my previous question i should be able to solve this problem on myself, but i just can't get my head around this pivot, unpivot part.

Also if you need the sample data in a more SQL way, you can try this one:

```
DECLARE @src AS TABLE
    (
     ID int NOT NULL
    ,Label varchar(14) NOT NULL
    ,Numerator int NOT NULL
    ,Denominator int NOT NULL
    ,Ratio decimal(10, 4) NOT NULL
    ) ;

INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameOne', 41, 10, 4.1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameThree', 21, 10, 2.1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameFour', 15, 10, 1.5) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameOne', 19, 19, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameThree', 15, 16, 0.9375) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameFive', 19, 19, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameSix', 17, 17, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameOne', 12, 12, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameThree', 11, 12, 0.9167) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameFour', 12, 12, 1) ;
INSERT  INTO @src
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameSix', 0, 1, 0) ;
```

Comment: Similar to the answer I provided on the first question, the only way to do what you want is dynamic SQL which is generally not recommended. T-SQL wasn't designed for producing this sort of output. You should instead simply return your raw data to the middle-tier or reporting tool and "pivot" the data there.

Comment: I have to disagree with @Thomas. While dynamic SQL is the appropriate solution here, keep in mind that it isn't good/bad, recommended/not. It's simply a tool. Take a look at http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html for more info on dynamic T-SQL.

Comment: @Jeremiah - IMO we should differentiate what is possible from what is recommended. Yes, it is *possible* to produce any output you can imagine using dynamic SQL in T-SQL. However, just as a screwdriver is a neither a good nor bad tool itself and can be used for hammering nails, it is not the best tool for the job. T-SQL was not made for reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the labels before the PIVOT.  The column list also needs to take account of the cross join of label possibilities:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON ; 

DECLARE @pivot_cols AS varchar(max) ; 
DECLARE @src AS TABLE 
    ( 
     ID int NOT NULL 
    ,Label varchar(14) NOT NULL 
    ,Numerator int NOT NULL 
    ,Denominator int NOT NULL 
    ,Ratio decimal(5, 4) NOT NULL 
    ) ; 

DECLARE @label_order AS TABLE 
    ( 
     Label varchar(14) NOT NULL 
    ,Sort int NOT NULL 
    ) 

DECLARE @sub_label_order AS TABLE 
    ( 
     SubLabel varchar(14) NOT NULL 
    ,Sort int NOT NULL 
    ) 

INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameOne', 41, 10, 4.1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameThree', 21, 10, 2.1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, 'LabelNameFour', 15, 10, 1.5) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameOne', 19, 19, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameThree', 15, 16, 0.9375) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameFive', 19, 19, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, 'LabelNameSix', 17, 17, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameOne', 12, 12, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameTwo', 0, 0, 0) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameThree', 11, 12, 0.9167) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameFour', 12, 12, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, 'LabelNameSix', 0, 1, 0) ; 

INSERT  INTO @label_order 
VALUES  ('LabelNameOne', 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @label_order 
VALUES  ('LabelNameTwo', 2) ; 
INSERT  INTO @label_order 
VALUES  ('LabelNameThree', 3) ; 
INSERT  INTO @label_order 
VALUES  ('LabelNameFour', 4) ; 
INSERT  INTO @label_order 
VALUES  ('LabelNameFive', 5) ; 
INSERT  INTO @label_order 
VALUES  ('LabelNameSix', 6) ; 

INSERT  INTO @sub_label_order 
VALUES  ('Numerator', 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @sub_label_order 
VALUES  ('Denominator', 2) ; 
INSERT  INTO @sub_label_order 
VALUES  ('Ratio', 3) ; 

WITH    Labels 
          AS ( 
              SELECT  DISTINCT 
                        src.Label + sublabel.SubLabel AS Label
                       ,ISNULL(label_order.Sort, 0) AS Sort 
                       ,ISNULL(sublabel.Sort, 0) AS SubSort 
              FROM      @src AS src 
              CROSS JOIN @sub_label_order AS sublabel
              LEFT JOIN @label_order AS label_order 
                        ON src.label = label_order.label 
             ) 
    SELECT  @pivot_cols = COALESCE(@pivot_cols + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Label, '[') 
    FROM    Labels 
    ORDER BY Sort 
           ,SubSort
           ,Label ; 

DECLARE @template AS varchar(max) ; 

SET @template = ' 
DECLARE @src AS TABLE 
    ( 
     ID int NOT NULL 
    ,Label varchar(14) NOT NULL 
    ,Numerator int NOT NULL 
    ,Denominator int NOT NULL 
    ,Ratio decimal(5, 4) NOT NULL 
    ) ; 

INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameOne'', 41, 10, 4.1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameTwo'', 0, 0, 0) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameThree'', 21, 10, 2.1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (1, ''LabelNameFour'', 15, 10, 1.5) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameOne'', 19, 19, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameTwo'', 0, 0, 0) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameThree'', 15, 16, 0.9375) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameFive'', 19, 19, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (2, ''LabelNameSix'', 17, 17, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameOne'', 12, 12, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameTwo'', 0, 0, 0) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameThree'', 11, 12, 0.9167) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameFour'', 12, 12, 1) ; 
INSERT  INTO @src 
VALUES  (3, ''LabelNameSix'', 0, 1, 0) ; 

WITH    src_conformed 
          AS ( 
              SELECT    ID 
                       ,Label 
                       ,CAST (Numerator AS decimal(10, 4)) AS Numerator 
                       ,CAST (Denominator AS decimal(10, 4)) AS Denominator 
                       ,CAST (Ratio AS decimal(10, 4)) AS Ratio 
              FROM      @src 
             ), 
        UNPIVOTED 
          AS ( 
              SELECT    * 
              FROM      src_conformed UNPIVOT ( Val FOR Col IN (Numerator, Denominator, Ratio) ) AS unpvt 
             )
             ,COMBINED AS (SELECT  ID, Label + Col AS NewLabel, Val
    FROM    UNPIVOTED)
    SELECT *
    FROM    COMBINED PIVOT ( SUM(Val) FOR NewLabel IN ({@pivot_cols}) ) AS pvt 
     ORDER BY ID ;' ; 

SET @template = REPLACE(@template, '{@pivot_cols}', @pivot_cols) ; 

EXEC (@template) ;
```