# How to pivot data in SQL Server 2008 to get the desired results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

After getting already really good answer to this topic in the past ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2462942/1838048) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2433533/1838048)). It seems that I'm still not able to get me head around this pivot stuff (I also didn't used it for a long time).

So hopefully someone is (again) able to tell me how to get the data into the desired format:

Given data:

```
ID | Label | Occurences | RangeBegin | RangeEnd | Unit
---+-------+------------+------------+----------+--------
1  | One   | 0          | -1000      | 0        | m
1  | One   | 5          | 0          | 10       | m
1  | One   | 8          | 10         | 20       | m
1  | One   | 6          | 20         | 30       | m
1  | One   | 15         | 30         | 40       | m
1  | One   | 0          | 40         | 1000     | m
2  | One   | 0          | -1000      | 0        | m
2  | One   | 2          | 0          | 10       | m
2  | One   | 13         | 10         | 20       | m
2  | One   | 27         | 20         | 30       | m
2  | One   | 5          | 30         | 40       | m
2  | One   | 0          | 40         | 1000     | m
1  | Two   | 0          | -1000      | 0        | kg
1  | Two   | 4          | 0          | 2        | kg
1  | Two   | 6          | 2          | 4        | kg
1  | Two   | 1          | 4          | 6        | kg
1  | Two   | 0          | 6          | 1000     | kg
2  | Two   | 0          | -1000      | 0        | kg
2  | Two   | 8          | 0          | 2        | kg
2  | Two   | 1          | 2          | 4        | kg
2  | Two   | 3          | 4          | 6        | kg
2  | Two   | 0          | 6          | 1000     | kg
```

Desired result:

```
ID | One | OneRangeBegin | OneRangeEnd | OneUnit | Two  | TwoRangeBegin | TwoRangeEnd | TwoUnit
---+-----+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------+-------------+----------
 1 | 0   | -1000         | 0           | m       | 0    | -1000         | 0           | kg
 1 | 5   | 0             | 10          | m       | 4    | 0             | 2           | kg
 1 | 8   | 10            | 20          | m       | 6    | 2             | 4           | kg
 1 | 6   | 20            | 30          | m       | 1    | 4             | 6           | kg
 1 | 15  | 30            | 40          | m       | 0    | 6             | 1000        | kg
 1 | 0   | 40            | 1000        | m       | null | null          | null        | null
 2 | 0   | -1000         | 0           | m       | 0    | -1000         | 0           | kg
 2 | 2   | 0             | 10          | m       | 8    | 0             | 2           | kg
 2 | 13  | 10            | 20          | m       | 1    | 2             | 4           | kg
 2 | 27  | 20            | 30          | m       | 3    | 4             | 6           | kg
 2 | 5   | 30            | 40          | m       | 0    | 6             | 1000        | kg
 2 | 0   | 40            | 1000        | m       | null | null          | null        | null
```

Also to make the work on it a little bit easier, I put the data above at [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/192474/2).

Comment: You'll need to look at unpivot and pivot.  Have you tried any code to get the solution?

Comment: Post your query attempt and what went wrong with it.   Errors or unexpected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be achieved by doing something like this:

1. Split the Table based on Labels
2. Rank the each table by partitioning on ID and arranging it based on RangeBegin. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RangeBegin)`
3. Full join the Two Tables on ID and Rank

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/192474/25)

```
SELECT 
 A.ID AS ID
,A.Occurences AS One
,A.RangeBegin AS OneRangeBegin
,A.RangeEnd AS OneRangeEnd
,A.Unit AS OneUnit
,B.Occurences AS Two
,B.RangeBegin AS TwoRangeBegin
,B.RangeEnd AS TwoRangeEnd
,B.Unit AS TwoUnit


FROM
(select
*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RangeBegin) Rank
from
AvailableData
wHere Label = 'One') A
FULL JOIN
(select
*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID  ORDER BY RangeBegin) Rank
from
AvailableData
Where Label = 'Two' ) B
ON A.ID = B.ID
AND A.Rank = B.Rank
ORDER BY ISNULL(A.ID, B.ID), ISNULL(A.Rank, B.Rank)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always had difficulty wrapping my head around pivots as well.  For this reason, I tend to use the aggregate CASE method instead of PIVOT because I find it easier to reason about (and it's more flexible).  Basically you need to break down your problem into multiple steps.

1. Identify how the data is grouped - e.g., by ID, RangeBegin, RangeEnd
2. Identify what all the columns will be, and where they will be sourced
3. Write an aggregated CASE statement for each individual column - NOTE: You must ensure that every output is unambiguous, or you will get missing results

The general layout of an aggregated CASE pivot is like this:

```
SELECT
  grouped columns
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN condition THEN column END) as ColumnName
  ,...
FROM
  Table
GROUP BY grouped columns
```

The key is that the condition above will identify the source for each column.  So for example, the column `OneUnit` obviously comes from the `Unit` column when the `Label` column is `One`, so that would be:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Label='One' THEN Unit END) as OneUnit
```

This would be easy to apply to your specific example, except there isn't an obvious way to relate the rows from One to Two together, because you are combining different Ranges together.  You need to identify an unambiguous rule to combine rows together in the pivot before you can build the actual pivot query, which should then be pretty straightforward (this generates extra rows currently because the ranges are different between the One and Two sets):

```
select
  D.ID, D.RangeBegin, D.RangeEnd
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='One' THEN D.Occurences END) as One
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='One' THEN D.RangeBegin END) as OneRangeBegin
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='One' THEN D.RangeEnd END) as OneRangeEnd
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='One' THEN D.Unit END) as OneUnit
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='Two' THEN D.Occurences END) as Two
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='Two' THEN D.RangeBegin END) as TwoRangeBegin
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='Two' THEN D.RangeEnd END) as vRangeEnd
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Label='Two' THEN D.Unit END) as TwoUnit
from
  AvailableData D
group by
  D.ID, D.RangeBegin, D.RangeEnd
```